# Problems when storing and processing serial data

Tags: python, queue, python-multithreading, pyserial

I am reading serial data and trying to sort and display individual data packets.
The problem is that when I receive a packet, I can print it using print(), and the packet prints perfectly OK. But when I add this packet to the list[] or try to add the packet to Listbox(tkinter), the packets sometimes get combined/scrambled and I get two packets displayed as one longer packet.

- The serial data comes in irregular intervals and sometimes in bursts of few packets in a very short time.
- Packet length is variable between 9 and 26 ASCII characters, and it is terminated with \r
- Serial speed is at the moment limited to 115200, and this is a minimum speed to get bursts of packets transferred without chocking the communication.

Here is what I have tried so far:

- tried to run processing without the queue, just directly process packets as they come – result, print() all packets printed ok, but when adding packets to list[] and/or Listbox(tkinter) some packets were combined into single packet.
- tried to implement the FIFO queue, and add packets to the queue in one thread, and remove/process them in the other thread, so I thought they will be completely independent - result  - same as above, print() all packets printed ok, but when adding packets to list[] and/or Listbox(tkinter) some packets were combined into single packet.

I have tried many variations of the code, and all of it failed. The print function displays packets correctly, but when I try to do anything with them, namely sort them into lists or add them to listbox, some of the packets get combined…. It seems that when packets are coming in bursts with minimal time delay between the packets, python can not process them fast enough? But the print function does keep up, and when I run separate threads for placing packets into queue and separate thread for reading them out of the queue, the timing should not be an issue, right?

Please help, I have exhausted all my ideas…

I am using serial read line function to get packets:

```
def serial_read_line(port):
    ser = serial.Serial(port, 115200, timeout=0.01)
    ser.flushInput()
    while 1:
        x = ser.readline()
        if len(x) < 1:
            pass
        else:
            y = str(x.decode('utf-8'))
            if y != x:
                x = y
                return y
```

The above function is run in a separate thread so it does not block the program.

```
# *********** Scanning for packets **********
# scan for incoming packets
# set global variable for start/stop packet scan
stop = 1
q1 = queue.Queue()


def ser_packet_scan():
    port = serial_port_selection.get()
    global q1
    while True:
        packet_1 = sio.serial_read_line(port)
        q1.put(packet_1)
        process_packets()
        if stop == 1:
            break


# starting thread for packet scan
def start_thread():
    global stop
    stop = 0
    th = Thread(target=ser_packet_scan)
    th.start()
    th2 = Thread(target=process_packets)
    th2.start()


# stopping thread for packet scan
def stop_thread():
    global stop
    stop = 1
```

The processing is run in a separate thread, I have also tried to run it in the main program thread.

```
def process_packets():
    # sort packets into lists
    global q1
    pckt_r = q1.get()
    print(pckt_r)
    pck.sort_into_lists(pckt_r)
    # update packet lists
    if list_box_selection.get() == 'Running':
        list_box_display.insert(0, pckt_r)
        # limit listbox display size
        if list_box_display.size() > 100:
            list_box_display.delete(END)
…
…
    # time.sleep(0.5) have tried with the sleep and without it… no diference...
    q1.task_done()
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution. I also found a couple of issues.

- print() function does automatically new line and it understands \r, so my print output was always correct even though the packet was consisting of two or more packets.
- the inbuilt function readline() did not work very well. Some packets were combined even though there was an \r character present.

Solution:
I have replaced inbuilt readline() with custom function:

```
def read_line_c(ser):
    buf = bytearray()
    i = buf.find(b"\r")
    if i >= 0:
        r = buf[:i + 1]
        buf[i + 1:]
        return r
    while True:
        i = max(1, min(2048, ser.in_waiting))
        data = ser.read(i)
        i = data.find(b"\r")
        if i >= 0:
            r = buf + data[:i + 1]
            buf[0:] = data[i + 1:]
            return r
        else:
            buf.extend(data)
```

The packets appear to be all OK with this custom readline, but I need to test it a bit more to see if there are any issues... Alternatively I could use the inbuilt readline(), and then look for packets which have \r in them and split them...